# Mapping Spray Parameters

Tags: scala, akka, spray

I am trying to build a simple API to understand Spray's capabilities and already am stuck by mapping parameters to real types.  I have the following code which fails to compile but I'm using it as documented in Spray's own documentation:

```
  val myRoute =
    pathPrefix("people") {
      path("nearby") {
        parameters('lat as[Double], 'lng as[Double]).as(Location) { location =>
          complete {
            locationWorker ! location
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

The error I receive is

[error] /.../MyService.scala:47: ')' expected but '[' found.

[error]         parameters('lat as[Double], 'lng as[Double]).as(Nearby) { lat =>

It's worth mentioning I am somewhat new to Scala as well so I could easily be doing something very simple wrong.

Comment: try to use it with dot, `'lat.as[Double]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am new to Scala/Akka etc and spent a bit of time stuck on a parameter mapping problem earlier this week. I will share what I have which is working and perhaps it can guide you down the correct path. By no-way is this telling you why Scala is choking on that symbol, but hopefully is helpful in some way.

My GET directive looks like this:

```
get { parameters('filter, 'sort ?, 'skip ?, 'take ?).as(Search) { model => complete { (account ? UserSearchReq(model)).mapTo[SearchResult[User]] } } } ~
```

And my search model looks like this:

```
case class Search(filter: String, sort: Option[String], skip: Option[Int], take: Option[Int])
```

As you can see, the filter is required, but the remaining parameters are optional. I have not specified the type, but everything works just fine.

Best of luck.